# "Remove HDR" / convert photo from rich to normal mode

Tags: camera, lumia-550, hdr

I really like the HDR option of the Windows phone camera app. Therefore I tend to use it almost as default. Sometimes when I later go through the photos I have taken I find some where the HDR mode doesn't really improve the image. Is it possible to convert these photos to "normal" so that they use less space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HDR mode takes multiple exposures upon pressing the shutter button. These exposures are stored in a .NAR file (same filename as the photo, but different extension) in your Camera Roll folder. If you want to free up disk space, simply use the File Explorer app to delete the .NAR file. This will leave the .JPG file containing the photo intact, just make sure you're happy with it first.

Comment: Note, however, that the .JPG is not the HDR image. The HDR image is contained in the .NAR file.

Comment: The .JPG is simply the blend between the multiple exposures or pre-composed images stored in the .NAR file. In that sense, it *is* "the HDR image", it's just that you need the .NAR file in order to tweak the blend. That's why I said to make sure you're happy with the .JPG file before deleting the .NAR file.

Comment: I had looked at a few images and gotten the opposite impression. But looking again, you're right. I retract my comment.